# In Nest (Elasticsearch), how can I get the raw json mapping of an index?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I want to check the discrepancies between my current mapping (as in my C# code) and the mapping in the elasticsearch index.

With only:

```cs
var res = esClient.GetMapping<EsCompany>();
```

I get `GetMappingResponse` object in c#, I will have to compare field by field for equality. Even worse, each field has their own properties, I have to descend into those properties for further comparison.

In my application, I prefer obtaining the raw json of the mapping, and I can easily diff two json objects for equality.

I then tried this:

```cs
var res = esClient.Raw.IndicesGetMapping(myIndexName);
```

But when I read `res.Response`, I get an `AmbiguousMatchException` exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you connect to Elasticsearch you can choose to expose the raw response like this:

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings().ExposeRawResponse());
```

Then you should be able to access the raw json via:

```cs
var json = res.ConnectionStatus.ResponseRaw;
```

Comment: I never thought about this. I spent some time going through all methods in ConnectionSettings and learned a few others I didn't know of. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a somewhat related question. I need to compare the mapping of the index in the elasticsearch server with the mapping defined in my code. But I can only create an index (via `CreateIndex`) with the new mapping first and then read the json mapping from there. Is there a way to get the Json mapping without actually creating an index?

Comment: @foresightyj, yes - serialize the create index descriptor with NEST's serializer to get the json without needing to make a request.

Comment: Is `.ExposeRawResponse()` still available? Because I don't see it.